# Spring boot @Cacheable - how can I set refresh interval/clear interval?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I have service:

```
@Service
public class ErrMessageServiceImpl implements ErrMessageService {

  private final ErrMessageRepository errMessageRepository;

  public ErrMessageServiceImpl(ErrMessageRepository errMessageRepository) {
    this.errMessageRepository = errMessageRepository;
  }

  @Override
  @Cacheable("errorMessages")
  public ErrMessage getOneByCode(int code) {
    return errMessageRepository.getOneByCode(code);
  }
}
```

I read that this default implementation work with `ConcurrentHashMap`

> Initially, the project does not define any caching library so the
>   abstraction works on simple ConcurrentHashMap-based caches. You can
>   try out your favorite caching library as explained below. [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache)

All work fine. But now I need `refresh Cache` every 10 minutes. But I not understand how can I do it? I suspect I need use some provider and configure it - `Caffeine`, `Redis` and etc. Or I can configure default `ConcurrentHashMap` and set refresh interval?

Comment: You can do this even without configuring any cachemanager as indicated by most of the answers in the link. Check `@Scheduled` and @CacheEvict

Comment: There is no option for auto-refresh/auto clear in @Cacheable. But you can write your own schedule for this purpose. Follow this https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/06/building-your-own-self-refreshing-cache-in-java-ee/